# display content class xaml vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Well i have a mainWindow written in xaml (vb.net) with 10 buttons and for each button i have a class (with buttons...) in my project. Example: when i click on button valid i display the content of the class valid in my grid. Each class is instantiated in the class mainWdow.
I also have a grid on this mainWindow.
When i click on a button in my mainWindow, i would like to display the content of the correspondig class in my grid and of course i want to be able to use this class (click on buttons...).

What's the best way to do this on vb.net / xaml please?

On this webpage [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903947(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903947%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) there are some indications but it is not what i want because i don't want just only display the content on my class but i want to be able to work with the class displayed on my grid...

I give you thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first you should read up about `DataTemplate`s from the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN. Now here is the basic principal... instead of putting your reusable XAML into `Window`s, declare them in `DataTemplate`s in your `Window.Resources` section:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StopDataTemplate">
    <!--Define your content here-->
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ValidDataTemplate">
    <!--Define your content here-->
</DataTemplate>
```

Now you can display the content of these `DataTemplate`s in a `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ValidDataTemplate}" />
```

Then when you want to switch to the other view, you just need to set the `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` property to the other `DataTemplate` (from `Window` code behind):

```
DataTemplate dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("StopDataTemplate");
Content.ContentTemplate = dataTemplate;
```

Comment: Hm ok that's very interesting, first i'm going to write some code by myself and test it before to post another response. But just one question: when i will display for example validDataTemplate, could i use the buttons of validDataTemplate with theirs events?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is what i have done to do some tests:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<DataTemplate x:Key="CBTemplate">
    <Grid Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="centralGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Background="Red">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" 
                    Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

then in my mainWindow.xaml i have this:

```
<Grid x:Name="layout" Background="LightBlue" Margin="250,150,260,380">
        <ContentControl Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CBTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
```

And in the mainWindow.vb i have:

```
Class MainWindow
Private t As Thing

Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()

    t = New Thing("test")
    layout.DataContext = t
End Sub
```

End Class

So my program compiles properly but there is a little problem: text="{Binding Title}" doesn't work and when i replace it with "toto", there is no problem toto is displayed...
Did i miss something in my code?